# Linq to SQL simple SUM

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I was suggested from a friend the following code

var tmp = from allCourses in _db.tblCourseNeededHours orderby allCourses.tblCourse.CourseName where allCourses.Semester == semester select allCourses;

return tmp.Sum(x => x.NeededHoursPerWeek);

but i am receving this error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable

Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

public IQueryable FindSumAllCourseNeededHoursInSemester(string semester)

Comment: Based on your updates, I'm not sure why you need to use the grouping.  If each of the first two rows in your HTML table represents a record in your database table, I see no reason to group.  You just seem to want the sum of everything in that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris is correct if you want the complete total, if you want it by course name use GroupBy:

```
var hours = FindAllCourseNeededHoursInSemester(mySemester)
    .GroupBy(g => g.CourseName)
    .Select(c => new { c.Key, c.Sum(a => a.NeededHours) } );
```

Comment: What is the return type of your method that has the line return tmp.Sum(x = > x.NeededHoursPerWeek); ?

Comment: I made some edit above and the controllor looks like that  public ActionResult Index(string semester)

Comment: Your method where you have that return is specifying IQueryable. Your result is not that any more - by doing sum you now just have a double.

Comment: so what changes and where i should made?

Comment: @Jawad: Before your last edit, you had a method that returned an IQueryable of your filtered objects. You seem to now be trying to return the sum instead of the IQueryable.  You should either do the sum outside of your method or change the method's signature to return a double instead of the IQueryable.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
var sum = FindAllCourseNeededHoursInSemester(mySemester).Sum(course => course.NeededHours)
```

This MSDN article has a good primer on some common LINQ tasks:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I assume that the sum is wanted in the above query for each course rather than as an entirely separate calculation.

Comment: @Chris: I agree there's some ambiguity. I am a little confused about what his table really represents.  It seems a little strange to me to have a field called `NeededHours` in a table about courses. Seems like the concept of "need" for hours would be more applicable to a student or field of study than a course itself.

Comment: Ambiguity is annoying here. And I assumed that "neededHours" was how many hours the course lasted (so how many hours you need to do the course). that is an assumption though. ;-) It does remind me why good variable/field names is so important in making your code self-documented. :)